# Reuse buffer pointer with sprintf and PQexecParams

Tags: c, postgresql, buffer, printf

I'm doing sql request to a PostgreSQL database using PQexecParams function :

```
PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn,
                   const char *command,
                   int nParams,
                   const Oid *paramTypes,
                   const char * const *paramValues,
                   const int *paramLengths,
                   const int *paramFormats,
                   int resultFormat);
```

To pass paramValues, I use sprintf :

```
sprintf(buffer1, "%d", stats.packets_count);
values2[0] = buffer1;
sprintf(buffer2, "%d", stats.packets_count_gap);
values2[1] = buffer2;
sprintf(buffer3, "%f", stats.packets_mean);
values2[2] = buffer3;
sprintf(buffer4, "%f", stats.variance);
values2[3] = buffer4;
sprintf(buffer5, "%f", stats.square_mean);
values2[4] = buffer5;
sprintf(buffer6, "%f", stats.standard_deviation);
values2[5] = buffer6;
sprintf(buffer7, "%d", stats.is_ddos);
values2[6] = buffer7;
sprintf(buffer8, "%f", stats.threshold);
values2[7] = buffer8;
sprintf(buffer9, "%d", stats.bandwidth);
values2[8] = buffer9;
values2[9] = proto_name;
sprintf(buffer11, "%f", packet_proto_ratio);
values2[10] = buffer11;
sprintf(buffer12, "%f", tcp_sign_ratio);
values2[11] = buffer12;
sprintf(buffer13, "%d", inflow_outflow_gap);
values2[12] = buffer13;
sprintf(buffer14, "%f", bandwidth_ratio);
values2[13] = buffer14;
```

And here is the request :

```
result = PQexecParams(psql, "INSERT INTO statistics (packets_count, packets_count_gap,  mean, variance, square_mean, standard_deviation, is_ddos, date, threshold, bandwidth, protocol, packet_proto_ratio, tcp_sign_ratio, inflow_outflow_gap, bandwidth_ratio) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, now(), $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14);", 14, NULL, values2, lengths2, NULL, 0);
```

But it feel really dirty to do it this way, is there any way to reuse a single buffer pointer ? Because I have several place in my code that need to execute a sql request so i end up with a lot of buffers.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each buffer points to a separate chunk of memory, with a separate value in it. So no, you cannot reuse them. They must all remain valid and intact until you send them to the PostgreSQL server.

What you can do - if you know how big the total data set will be - is to allocate a single *big* buffer. Then advance the write pointer by the data length written whenever you append data to it. So all the pointers in the values array point to different, non-overlapping parts of the same client side buffer.

This is quite easy, as `sprintf` returns the number of characters printed, excluding the null terminator.